# Is it possible in Swift to add variables to an object at runtime?

Tags: swift

Specifically, I would like to add a variable of type enum to an instance of UIView, without subclassing or create an extension.

Thanks.

Comment: It may be possible using the ObjC runtime, which Swift shares. However, if one is considering this, it would be wise to have a long, hard think about, "Why do I need this? Do I really need this?" This isn't the standard way of doing things and can have many unforeseen pitfalls. There probably is a better way to accomplish your end goal.

Comment: If I did ask it's because I think that would be the best approach. I know the standard way (subclassing/extension -is there any more?), but none of them makes much sense in this case.
Thanks anyway.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the context? I'm always curious with questions like these.

Comment: I have to implement an UI widget (like a gallery) because any of the existences doesn't suit our needs. In order to achieve certain degree of abstraction, i've implemented a set of classes. One of them exposes -through a protocol- a method called getView(), which return the view create at the client side. Because this view is supply by the client every time the “gallery” requires the next item, It can’t be a sub-class of UIView. Even so, the class need to keep track of certain values, and I think it would be better if this information can added at runtime to the views as dynamic properties.

Comment: If your attempt at abstraction has led you into a corner like this where the runtime is the most attractive option, perhaps you should rethink it.  It sounds like you're trying to mix too much state back into your view layer.  Perhaps a ModelView could clean things up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The previous answer about objc_setAssociatedObject() is the right approach, but I think Apple's APIs for this have not yet been vetted, because I've had difficulty using them the way I think they ought to be used. (I shouldn't have to muck about with unsafe pointers and such.) Here's the solution I'm using now.

First, you need a bit of Objective-C glue (follow Apple's instructions for mixing Objective-C and Swift in the same project:

```
// RuntimeGlue.h
// Should be included from your bridging header.

@import Foundation;

void setAssociatedObject_glue(NSObject *object, const NSString *key, NSObject *value);
NSObject *getAssociatedObject_glue(NSObject *object, const NSString* key);


// RuntimeGlue.m

#import "RuntimeGlue.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

void setAssociatedObject_glue(NSObject *object, const NSString *key, NSObject *value) {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(object, (__bridge const void *)(key), value, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

NSObject *getAssociatedObject_glue(NSObject *object, const NSString* key) {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(object, (__bridge const void *)(key));
}
```

Next, the Swift methods you'll call from the rest of your program:

```
// Runtime.swift

import Foundation

public func setAssociatedObject(#object: NSObject, #key: NSString, #value: NSObject?) {
    setAssociatedObject_glue(object, key, value)
}

public func getAssociatedObject(#object: NSObject, #key: NSString) -> NSObject? {
    return getAssociatedObject_glue(object, key)
}
```

Finally, an example of use to tag a particular view controller's view as "debugging".

```
// MyViewController.swift

import UIKit

let debugKey: NSString = "DebugKey"

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setAssociatedObject(object: self.view, key: debugKey, value: "debugging")
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)  {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        let val = getAssociatedObject(object: self.view, key: debugKey)
        println("val:\(val)")
    }
}
```

This approach lets you pass `nil` for `value` to the setter in order to clear the value for the key, and returns an optional from the getter. Note also that the `key` argument must be identical in both cases (k1 === k2) and not merely equivalent (k1 == k2).

Also note that this only lets you tag instances of NSObject or its subclasses-- it does not work for Swift native classes. The `value` must also be an NSObject subclass, but both strings and number literals automatically bridge to Objective-C, so you don't need to do any explicit casting.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a simple but complete example derived from [jckarter's answer](https://devforums.apple.com/message/986325#986325).

It shows how to add a new property to an existing class. It does it by defining a computed property in an extension block. The computed property is stored as an associated object:

```
import ObjectiveC

// Declare a global var to produce a unique address as the assoc object handle
var AssociatedObjectHandle: UInt8 = 0

extension MyClass {
    var stringProperty:String {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedObjectHandle) as String
        }
        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedObjectHandle, newValue, objc_AssociationPolicy(OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `objc_setAssociatedObject()` function from the Objective-C runtime to attach an object (you can wrap that enum into an object) onto another object, and `objc_getAssociatedObject()` to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY_NONATOMIC